# Errors with "Back in Time"

Tags: backup, rsync

I get these errors with "Back in Time". Can someone explain how to avoid them?

```
[E] Error: rsync: symlink "/media/TREKSTOR/Sicherung/backintime/Refle/root/1/new_snapshot/backup/home/refle/.config/chromium/SingletonCookie" -> "11676890789582771720" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
[E] Error: rsync: symlink "/media/TREKSTOR/Sicherung/backintime/Refle/root/1/new_snapshot/backup/home/refle/.config/chromium/SingletonLock" -> "Refle-2305" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
[E] Error: rsync: symlink "/media/TREKSTOR/Sicherung/backintime/Refle/root/1/new_snapshot/backup/home/refle/.config/chromium/SingletonSocket" -> "/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.nSUOLR/SingletonSocket" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
[E] Error: rsync: symlink "/media/TREKSTOR/Sicherung/backintime/Refle/root/1/new_snapshot/backup/home/refle/.kde/socket-Refle" -> "/tmp/ksocket-refle" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
[E] Error: rsync: symlink "/media/TREKSTOR/Sicherung/backintime/Refle/root/1/new_snapshot/backup/home/refle/.kde/tmp-Refle" -> "/tmp/kde-refle" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
[E] Error: rsync: symlink "/media/TREKSTOR/Sicherung/backintime/Refle/root/1/new_snapshot/backup/home/refle/.pulse/a720e9d91d67a4671223dd9100000009-runtime" -> "/tmp/pulse-yd4kGx1FIvgw" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
[E] Error: rsync: mkstemp "/media/TREKSTOR/Sicherung/backintime/Refle/root/1/new_snapshot/backup/home/refle/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/.afc:host=c0d85dff9221e93bd569ad19c719a9cc812cc00a.pRRwoB" failed: Invalid argument (22)
[E] Error: rsync: mkstemp "/media/TREKSTOR/Sicherung/backintime/Refle/root/1/new_snapshot/backup/home/refle/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/.afc:host=c0d85dff9221e93bd569ad19c719a9cc812cc00a,port=3.5FFq0l" failed: Invalid argument (22)
[E] Error: rsync: mkstemp "/media/TREKSTOR/Sicherung/backintime/Refle/root/1/new_snapshot/backup/home/refle/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/.afc:host=c0d85dff9221e93bd569ad19c719a9cc812cc00a,port=3-c2bd17dd.log.Dw3kC6" failed: Invalid argument (22)
[E] Error: rsync: mkstemp "/media/TREKSTOR/Sicherung/backintime/Refle/root/1/new_snapshot/backup/home/refle/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/.afc:host=c0d85dff9221e93bd569ad19c719a9cc812cc00a-1da33d62.log.u2BigR" failed: Invalid argument (22)
[E] Error: rsync: symlink "/media/TREKSTOR/Sicherung/backintime/Refle/root/1/new_snapshot/backup/home/refle/Documents/Studium/Uni **/Verknüpfung mit Programmieren" -> "/host/Users/**/Documents/Studium/Uni Bayreuth/Programmieren" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
[E] Error: rsync: symlink "/media/TREKSTOR/Sicherung/backintime/Refle/root/1/new_snapshot/backup/home/refle/Ubuntu One/Shared With Me" -> "/home/refle/.local/share/ubuntuone/shares" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Looks as though you're facing two different types of errors here.

```
[E] Error: rsync: mkstemp "/media/TREKSTOR/Sicherung/backintime/Refle/root/1/new_snapshot/backup/home/refle/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/.afc:host=c0d85dff9221e93bd569ad19c719a9cc812cc00a.pRRwoB" failed: Invalid argument (22)
[E] Error: rsync: mkstemp "/media/TREKSTOR/Sicherung/backintime/Refle/root/1/new_snapshot/backup/home/refle/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/.afc:host=c0d85dff9221e93bd569ad19c719a9cc812cc00a,port=3.5FFq0l" failed: Invalid argument (22)
[E] Error: rsync: mkstemp "/media/TREKSTOR/Sicherung/backintime/Refle/root/1/new_snapshot/backup/home/refle/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/.afc:host=c0d85dff9221e93bd569ad19c719a9cc812cc00a,port=3-c2bd17dd.log.Dw3kC6" failed: Invalid argument (22)
[E] Error: rsync: mkstemp "/media/TREKSTOR/Sicherung/backintime/Refle/root/1/new_snapshot/backup/home/refle/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/.afc:host=c0d85dff9221e93bd569ad19c719a9cc812cc00a-1da33d62.log.u2BigR" failed: Invalid argument (22)
```

These are due to your file name syntax. Rsync (the command line backend of Back in Time) [does not support colons in file names](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11581/rsync-colon-in-file-names). I don't know how Back in Time's configuration works, but with rsync you can define exclusion rules that will allow you to ignore these files.

---

```
[E] Error: rsync: symlink "/media/TREKSTOR/Sicherung/backintime/Refle/root/1/new_snapshot/backup/home/refle/.config/chromium/SingletonCookie" -> "11676890789582771720" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
[E] Error: rsync: symlink "/media/TREKSTOR/Sicherung/backintime/Refle/root/1/new_snapshot/backup/home/refle/.config/chromium/SingletonLock" -> "Refle-2305" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
[E] Error: rsync: symlink "/media/TREKSTOR/Sicherung/backintime/Refle/root/1/new_snapshot/backup/home/refle/.config/chromium/SingletonSocket" -> "/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.nSUOLR/SingletonSocket" failed: Operation not permitted (1)
```

What you're facing here are permission errors. The files you are trying to back up might have been created by a root user and as a result you don't have read access to them. Try checking the files' permissions from your file manager (*Properties* --> *Permissions*).

I would advise you to try and exclude these files from your back up. From what I can see they are mainly lock files and sockets that shouldn't be backed up.